# Can we filter out records with z-score <-3 or >3, if data type is 'timestamp'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, outliers

I'm trying to kick out any/all records with a z-score +- 3.  I'm testing the code below.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(df))
print(z)

# detect and remove outliers
df_filtered = df
[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

The task should be pretty simple, but apparently things get thrown off if there are fields with timestamps in the dataframe.  This line of code throws an error.

```
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(df))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'
```

The datatpe is this: `datetime64[ns]`

Here is a small sample of this specific data.

```
0    2021-01-16 06:10:11
1    2021-01-16 06:10:11
2    2021-01-16 06:10:11
3    2021-01-16 06:10:11
4    2021-01-16 06:10:11
5    2021-01-16 06:10:11
```

I'm just looking for a basic solution to test all fields in the dataframe simultaneously.  If that's not possible, I can change the code to look just at 4 fields, specifically, that have timestamps as data types.  Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Please share some sample data.

Comment: I just updated my original post.